# How can I relay a audio stream from browser to Google Speech API?

Tags: google-speech-api

I am developing speech-to-text web application with Google Speech API, and stucked.
Problem is, I do not understand how to relay audio stream from browser to Google Speech API.

I want Google Speech API to convert audio stream to text on real time, but it requires secret API key. So I guess I have to relay audio stream by my own server application.

Does my idea make sense?

Any advise is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Based on my understanding of the google APIs, the API key you need is just something associated with your google personal google account and the domain the web app will be hosted on. I've used a google API key before that did not at all require anything server-side.

Comment: @EthanReesor Thank you for advise. Could you tell me a reference url? I have to study about it...!